# Exporting polygons and their associated text to a DXF in QGIS

Tags: qgis

1. I have a layer called polygons in QGIS 3.4 and i make the text attribute "PID" visible on screen within each polygon.
2. I select several polygons with the visible "PID" text attribute.
3. I then go to Vector..Geometry Tools..Polygons to Lines, and convert the polygons to "lines".
4. I then export these lines to a dxf.
5. I open the dxf and the polygons are visible, but no text is showing.